# how to define width and height in autotable

Tags: javascript, jspdf-autotable

my code

```
$("#button1").on('click', exportOne);
function exportOne()
 {
 var pdf = new jsPDF("p", "pt","a4");

 var res = pdf.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("table2"));

 pdf.autoTable(res.columns, res.data);

var res2 = pdf.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("table"));
pdf.autoTable(res2.columns, res2.data, {
startY: pdf.autoTableEndPosY() + 16.6
});

pdf.fromHTML($("#otherdivcontent").get(0), 70, 300, {
'width': 500
});

// pdf.autoPrint();

pdf.save('Report.pdf');
};
```

the generated pdf is this
[image: output]

how can i solve this..i want to print the whole table inside in the page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 pdf.autoTable(res2.columns, res2.data, {
     startY: false,
     theme: 'grid',
     tableWidth: 'auto',
     columnWidth: 'wrap',
     showHeader: 'everyPage',
     tableLineColor: 200,
     tableLineWidth: 0,
     columnStyles: {
         0: {
             columnWidth: 50
         },
         1: {
             columnWidth: 50
         },
         2: {
             columnWidth: 50
         },
         3: {
             columnWidth: 50
         },
         4: {
             columnWidth: 50
         },
         5: {
             columnWidth: 'auto'
         },
         6: {
             columnWidth: 50
         },
         7: {
             columnWidth: 50
         },
         8: {
             columnWidth: 'auto'
         }
     },
     headerStyles: {
         theme: 'grid'
     },
     styles: {
         overflow: 'linebreak',
         columnWidth: 'wrap',
         font: 'arial',
         fontSize: 10,
         cellPadding: 8,
         overflowColumns: 'linebreak'
     },
 });
```

pdf[image: pdf]

Comment: Working like a charm